# MSAL 2.0 redirects with hash instead of query separator in url on my vanilla.js project

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm unable to get MSAL to redirect into endpoint on my Node.js backend. How to get rid of that damn hashtag and replace it with "?" so that my backend gets the MSAL code and can validate token. Now the token never reaches the server side as it is: https://urlurlurl.com/redirect#code=0.ASAAjymFZ1

My poor MS copy-paste interface code looks as in below

```
   const msalConfig  = {
    auth: {
      clientId: "guid",
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/numbers",
      validateAuthority: true,
      redirectUri: "https://url/redirect", //defaults to application start page
      postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://url/logout"
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false
    }
};

const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["User.Read"]   
};
const ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
const msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
const msie11 = ua.indexOf("Trident/");
const msedge = ua.indexOf("Edge/");
const isIE = msie > 0 || msie11 > 0;
const isEdge = msedge > 0;

let signInType;
let accountId = "";

/*
 * Create the main myMSALObj instance
 * configuration parameters are located at authConfig.js
 */
const myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig); 

// Register Callbacks for Redirect flow
myMSALObj.handleRedirectPromise().then(handleResponse).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});

function handleResponse(resp) {
    if (resp !== null) {
        accountId = resp.account.homeAccountId;
        showWelcomeMessage(resp.account);
        seeProfileRedirect();
    } else {
        // need to call getAccount here?
        const currentAccounts = myMSALObj.getAllAccounts();
        if (!currentAccounts || currentAccounts.length < 1) {
            signIn("loginRedirect");
        } else if (currentAccounts.length > 1) {
            // Add choose account code here
        } else if (currentAccounts.length === 1) {
            accountId = currentAccounts[0].homeAccountId;
            showWelcomeMessage(currentAccounts[0]);
        }
    }
}

async function signIn(method) {
    signInType = isIE ? "loginRedirect" : method;
    if (signInType === "loginPopup") {
        return myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest).then(handleResponse).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    } else if (signInType === "loginRedirect") {
        return myMSALObj.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
    }
}
```

Backend error says:

```
{
"errorCode": "request_cannot_be_made",
"errorMessage": "Token request cannot be made without authorization code or refresh token.",
"subError": "",
"name": "ClientAuthError"
}
```

Comment: Seems that problem refers to response mode which I now need to somehow change into query instead of fragment... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: const loginRequest = {
  responseMode:"query",
  scopes:["user.readl"]
}; should make the trick.. Gotta try tomorrow back at the office... If anyone from MS is reading - please at least comment this in some of developer tutorials as seems issue raised not only by me.

Comment: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2228

Wrong library being used. MS with their documentation is crap.

Comment: What do you want to do? Using auth code flow with MSAL?